# what is the meaning of 'window' in results from k8s metric server api

Tags: kubernetes-metrics

When I type this command on cli:

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/<NAMESPACE>/pods/<POD_NAME> | jq
```

I can get these results as below:

```
{
  "kind": "PodMetrics",
  "apiVersion": "metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "busybox",
    "namespace": "default",
    "selfLink": "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/busybox",
    "creationTimestamp": "2019-12-10T18:23:20Z"
  },
  "timestamp": "2019-12-10T18:23:12Z",
  "window": "30s",
  "containers": [
    {
      "name": "busybox",
      "usage": {
        "cpu": "0",
        "memory": "364Ki"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the meaning of that "window" item?
I am really want to know what it is exactly.

Comment: CPU is reported as the average usage, in CPU cores, over a period of time. This value is derived by taking a rate over a cumulative CPU counter provided by the kernel (in both Linux and Windows kernels). The kubelet chooses the window for the rate calculation. Obtained from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-cpu-usage-is-calculated) but not sure if it is representing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to k8s [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/v0.21.2/pkg/apis/metrics/types.go#L67-L70):

```golang
// PodMetrics sets resource usage metrics of a pod.
type PodMetrics struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta
    metav1.ObjectMeta

    // The following fields define time interval from which metrics were
    // collected from the interval [Timestamp-Window, Timestamp].
    Timestamp metav1.Time
    Window    metav1.Duration

    // Metrics for all containers are collected within the same time window.
    Containers []ContainerMetrics
}
```

You are most likely interested in this comment:

> **The following fields define time interval from which metrics were collected from the interval [Timestamp-Window, Timestamp].**

So the usage result is an averaged data gathered over this window/interval.

Comment: I really really appreciate your helps. thank you very much!!

Comment: Hello @irrain, please consider accepting or upvoting the answer if you found it helpful. stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment